# Python: Calculating weekly transportation options

Tags: python

I have two dicts that track the type of transportation I use over a weekly period:

```
transportation = {
    'car':[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    'walk':[0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
    'bike':[0,1,1,0,1,0,0],
 }

grains = {
    'overall':['car','walk','bike'],
    'environmentally_friendly':['walk','bike'],
 }
```

I would like to rollup the data to calculate when I was using transportation over the past week:

```
using_transportation = {
    'overall': 6,
    'environmentally_friendly': 4,
 }
```

If the week is Sunday through Saturday, `overall` is 6 because I do not use transportation on Friday. `environmentally_friendly` is 4 because Monday I walk and bike (only counts as 1), and then either walk or bike Tues - Thurs.

This is what I'm using for calculating overall, but not sure how to break out for environmentally_friendly (can't use pandas unfortunately):

```
week = []
day = []

i = 0
while i <= 6:
    for k,v in datelist.items():
        day.append(v[i])
    if 1 in day:
        week.append(True)
    else:
        week.append(False)
    day = []
    i+=1

print(sum(week))
```

Any advice on a better way is much appreciated!

Comment: Before looking for the best way, have you tried _any_ way that worked? Please include your attempt and explain why you are not happy with it.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to add three (two) lists and count the not-zero values. "Best way" is a bit vague though, What is "best" to you? Fastest? Most pythonic? Most simple?

Comment: Sorry, just added how I am calculating `overall`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you could solve the problem:

```py
transportation = {                                                              
     'car':[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],                                                      
     'walk':[0,1,0,1,0,0,0],                                                     
     'bike':[0,1,1,0,1,0,0],                                                     
  }                                                                              
                                                                                 
 grains = {                                                                      
     'overall':['car','walk','bike'],                                            
     'environmentally_friendly':['walk','bike'],                                 
  }                                                                              
                                                                                 
 def save_the_planet(transportation, grains):                                    
     # Let't do the week plan (as a bonus)                                       
     def go(x, i): return [k for (k, v) in x.items() if v[i] == 1]               
     week = {                                                                    
             'monday':       go(transportation, 0),                              
             'tuesday':      go(transportation, 1),                              
             'wednesday':    go(transportation, 2),                              
             'thursday':     go(transportation, 3),                              
             'friday':       go(transportation, 4),                              
             'saturday':     go(transportation, 5),                              
             'sunday':       go(transportation, 6),                              
             }                                                                   
                                                                                 
     # Now lets calculate                                                        
     overall     = transportation.keys()                                         
     not_eco     = [x for x in overall if x not in grains['environmentally_friendly']]
     not_eco     = {k:v for k,v in week.items() if any([x in v for x in not_eco])}
     eco_week    = {k:v for k,v in week.items() if k not in not_eco.keys()}         
                                                                                   
     # Then le'ts reveal the answer                                              
     return {                                                                       
             'overall': len([x for x in week.values() if x]),                       
             'environmentally_friendly': len([x for x in eco_week.values() if x]),
             }                                                                      
                                                                                    
print(save_the_planet(transportation, grains))
```

You can probably optimize it a bit